# Install4j project migrated from MAC to Windows does not install user created new file set

Tags: install4j

I created a project on MAC for building MAC installer in which I had defined many new file set other than default file set. I tried to use the same project file on windows to created windows installer. The installer was built successfully but after installation I checked that the file/folders which were defined in the new file set were not installed. When I checked in Build Output under Install4j tool there was some entry like below for copying these new file set:

Copying XYZ(existing: true, excluded: false) to **.i4j_external_290**\TEST

where as for the default file set there was nothing like  **.i4j_external_290** and it was relative path to Installation directory.

Comment: The project file is platform-independent. Switch on verbose output during build to check what files are packed into the installer.

Comment: The problem got fixed. The file set  were not getting included in the installation component.